# Update method in web API: How to know which fields to update?

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, asp.net-web-api, design-patterns

I have a typical web API with a couple of PUT/UPDATE endpoints. These endpoints simply call the underlying service, and do the update.

The service layer, has the typical signature such as `Object Update(Object object)`. What I then do is I basically run the following pseudo code:

```
var dbobject = _db.Object.Find(object.Id);    
dbobject.Field1 = object.Field1;
dbobject.Field2 = object.Field2;
// continue for all fields

_db.SaveChanges();

return GetObjectById(object.Id);
```

However, this provides a challenge for me.

Lets say we have a consumer of our API. This consumer calls my PUT endpoint (`/api/Object/{id}`), and the payload is the updated Object.

However, lets say that the object we put don't know about example `Field4`, then this value would be `NULL` after the update has been run.

**My question is:**

- What do you do about all those fields the payload does NOT contain? 
  How do you handle not setting values to NULL you don't expect to be
  NULL afterwards?

Comment: You could check each property to see if it's null. If it is null, you leave the original value in place. If it's not null, you use the new value. Of course, this leaves the question, how does one intentionally update a value to be null?

Comment: Using a framework such as AutoMapper instead of manually setting each field/property would give you more flexibility in this regard I feel.

Comment: How would you differentiate if it was set to NULL or just not provided?

Comment: And in case of non-nullable fields you'll never get NULL, but default value instead. which is you never know if "Amount is 0 or just wasn't changed"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As one of the possible ways, here can be used mix of `NotifyPropertyChanged` with `automapper`

The Idea is to store in DTO object which fields exactly was set, and which stays filled with default value. And use collected data in mapping.

For example DTO object will be

```
public class Dto
{
    private List<string> Changed = new List<string>();
    public bool IsChanged(string field) => Changed.Contains(field);

    private int _age;
    private string _name;

    public string Name
    {
        get { return _name; }
        set
        {
            _name = value;
            // IMPORTANT: field name should fit main object field name
            Changed.Add("Name"); 
        }
    }

    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set
        {
            _age = value;
            Changed.Add("Age");
        }
    }
}
```

I used Next class for test

```
public class Human
{
    public string Name { get; set; } = "DEFAULT";
    public int Age { get; set; } = -1;
}
```

and automapper configuration will looks like

```
cfg.CreateMap<Dto, Human>()
       .ForAllMembers(s=> s.Condition(d=>d.IsChanged(s.DestinationMember.Name)));
```

This is a simple example. But it still doesn't prevent to use function `IsChanged` for some complex/specific logic, use not just a strings but `Expressions` / `MethodInfo`, or add custom attributes and use them in automapper configuration (`DestinationMember` is `MethodInfo`)

### Append

Instead of complex DTO object the information about passed field you can get from `Request.Properties` in your controller (key `ms_querynamevaluepairs` value of type `Dictionary<string, string>`).